# Why is Parker hostile towards Ash?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Shortly after the captain is killed, Ripley asks Parker to refill a flamethrower and Parker explicitly rejects Ash helping him, saying, "Don't follow me!"

Of course, no one knows Ash is a replicant at this point and while Ripley already dislikes him immensely because of the quarantine thing, this was done on Dallas' orders and if anyone is really disliked, it could be Ripley herself -- Lambert actually slapped Ripley's face over her wanting to keep them outside. So at least Lambert and Dallas might really like Ash although Parker might now be resenting Ash because he is responsible for the xenomorph being on the ship -- and the xeno did just kill his friend and coworker.

So just what does account for Parker's special hostility towards Ash but not towards, say, Dallas?

Is it a general creepy vibe which is exacerbated perhaps by the "class" resentment -- Ash is this polished guy with a British accent -- and perhaps also that no one knows Ash as IIRC he was a replacement for another crewmember?